# Google drive file upload API with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to use Google drive API Integration with php application to upload/get files into my drive without asking users to login to Gmail while uploading.

Is it possible with Drive API? I tried uploading a file into drive with basic form.It is working ,But in my application the user should not ask for login and user uploaded file must be stored in my drive.(i.e, I am using my Drive as just for storing user uploaded files ).

Is it possible? And how could I do it with Codeigniter? I have working copy in php.

Comment: Sorry i cant help with Codeigniter but check out service accounts. Tip: Give the service account email address permissions to a folder on your drive account will give it access to upload to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Instead of using an access token associated with the user, you need a refresh token associated with your target Drive account. The steps to do this are here [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)